# Salt with Jinja condition

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am trying to execute a salt state depending on the IP first digit.

```
{% if grains['fqdn_ip4'].startswith('10') %}
task
{% endif %}
```

I get :

```
failed: Jinja variable 'list object' has no attribute 'startswith'
```

My syntax seems to be good, if I replace the grain item fqdn_ip4 with id, it works :

```
{% if grains['id'].startswith('10') %}
task
{% endif %}
```

The format seems different though :

```
salt-call grains.get id
```

returns

```
local:
admin.local
```

And

```
salt-call grains.get fqdn_ip4
```

returns

```
local:
- 10.25.64.33
```

So I have a "-" in front of fqdn_ip4 value.

Thanks in advance,

B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the error and `grains.get` output, we can see that the `fqdn_ip4` grain is a list/array. On machines with more than 1 IP address this grain will contain multiple elements.

Example:

```
minion:
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 1.2.3.4
  - 5.6.7.8
```

So if you want to match condition with the *first* element of the list, you have to use `grains['fqdn_ip4'][0]`. Like below:

```yaml
{% if grains['fqdn_ip4'][0].startswith('10') %}
show-ip:
  module.run:
    - name: test.echo
    - text: grains['fqdn_ip4'][0]
{% endif %}
```